# No glyph for U+000A in font NotoSerifDevanagari-Bold

Tags: java, android, pdfbox

i am trying to create pdf using pdfbox. i am storing EditText data as html in Sqlite DB.

now i am retrieving data from sqliteDB and creating pdf of that. this data is having marathi language as well as english language.

i am using ***NotoSerifDevanagari-Bold*** font and have added it to assets folder. from there i am accessing this font into code. but i am getting error. please find my code and error below.

```
AssetManager assetManager;
PDFBoxResourceLoader.init(getApplicationContext());
File FilePath = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS);
assetManager = getAssets();

PDDocument document = new PDDocument();
PDPage page = new PDPage();
document.addPage(page);

PDFont font = PDType0Font.load(document, assetManager.open("notoserifdevanagaribold.ttf"));
PDPageContentStream contentStream;
// Define a content stream for adding to the PDF
contentStream = new PDPageContentStream(document, page);

Cursor data = mDatabaseHelper.getDataByDeckname(deckname);
StringBuilder builder=new StringBuilder();
while (data.moveToNext()) {
    String front_page_desc = data.getString(3);
    String back_page_desc =  data.getString(4);

    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(15, 38, 192);
    contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);
    contentStream.showText(Html.fromHtml(front_page_desc).toString());
    contentStream.endText();

    contentStream.beginText();
    contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(15, 38, 192);
    contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
    contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);
    contentStream.showText(Html.fromHtml(back_page_desc).toString());
    contentStream.endText();
}

contentStream.close();

String path = FilePath.getAbsolutePath() + "/temp.pdf";
document.save(path);
document.close();
```

#### ERROR

```
W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+000A in font NotoSerifDevanagari-Bold
```

I tried so many examples for above error but i am not able to fix the issue. this error i am getting on ***contentStream.showText(Html.fromHtml(front_page_desc).toString());*** line. can someone please help me on above.

Comment: if i am replacing ***contentStream.showText(Html.fromHtml(front_page_desc).toString());*** with ***contentStream.showText(" TEsting content page back");*** then also i am getting same error.

Comment: Newline is not glyph.

Comment: i have removed ***contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);*** but then also i am getting same error.

Comment: *'`contentStream.showText(" TEsting content page back");` then also i am getting same error.'* - as there appears to be no U+000A character in that string, that is hard to believe.

Comment: can you please explain bit i have not understood properly.  what char should be there so that my code will run.

Comment: According to the exception text, you have a newline control character (`'\n'` / U+000A) in your string. This makes no sense, you will hardly ever find a font with a glyph for that control character. Thus, you should make sure that your `contentStream.showText` argument does not contain newline (or other) control characters. Then you claimed that in `contentStream.showText(" TEsting content page back")` you get the same error. That is hard to believe as that string appears not to contain a newline character.

Comment: yes but i am getting error for  below code  ```ContentStream.beginText();
                contentStream.setNonStrokingColor(15, 38, 192);
                contentStream.setFont(font, 12);
                contentStream.newLineAtOffset(100, 700);
                contentStream.showText(" TEsting content page back");
                contentStream.endText();```    ***error***   ```java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: No glyph for U+0054 in font NotoSerifDevanagari-Bold```

Comment: in my above code the string variable will be having HTML content so  i am using    ***Html.fromHtml(front_page_desc).toString()*** also i dont know what tags or if new line is there or not in string as it is coming from DB.i am using 
 ***Html.toHtml(frontedit.getText());*** method to convert my edittext string to html so that bold and all will be saved as html in DB. now i want to retrieve and put in pdf. but i am facing this issue.  ***Html.fromHtml(front_page_desc).toString()*** will bring it in html format i want to put same in pdf.

Comment: You need to split at the newlines and then handle each line separately. See the source of the TextToPDF command line tool how to do this.

Comment: "No glyph for U+0054" - that is a "T". Maybe that font just doesn't have that glyph. Does your font have latin glyphs at all?

Comment: Btw if you want to convert HTML to PDF, try https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf

Comment: on this link https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf so many examples are there i am not able to find the proper code

Comment: i am having html in one string variable i want to create pdf of that content

Comment: This shows how to get started: https://github.com/danfickle/openhtmltopdf/wiki/Integration-Guide

Answer (score 0):

As per [this link](https://www.compart.com/en/unicode/U+000A) U+000A is the Unicode for new line. Any font will fail if you try to render it.
In order to avoid such error you can try something like this:

```
 String[] lines = text.split("\\n");
        for (String line : lines) {
            if (!line.isBlank()) {
                contentStream.showText(line);
               // add new line here if you want to
            }
        }
```